# Git add first file from git status list?

Tags: git

I have a "lazy" type of question.
Imagine a list of newly added files to the project in the `git status` list output.
Is there a shortcut to `git add` the first file in that list without typing its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any shortcut, but you can script it on your own pretty easily.

```sh
git add $(git status --porcelain | sed s/^...// | head -n 1)
```

You can try to either add [aliases using Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) or just for your shell (like [bash, zsh](https://medium.com/devnetwork/how-to-create-your-own-custom-terminal-commands-c5008782a78e)).

Answer (score 0):

I have this as an alias in my own git:

```
git config --global alias.add1 '!f() { git add $(git status --porcelain | sed s/^...// | head -n 1); }; f'
```

I can now call it using `git add1`. If you want another alias, you can change the `alias.your_name` to your preference.

Since there is an expression substition `$()`, we cannot write is as a "standard" alias:

```
git config --global alias.add1 'add $(git status --porcelain | sed s/^...// | head -n 1); }; f'
```

So therefore we use `!` that allows us to [run external commands in an alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases), and wrap the expression in a function, and call the function.